# How to choose a web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, web-applications, web-hosting

I'm developing a new web app using ruby-on-rails and i want to host it but i don't know what is the best web hosting service for me.also want to know what type of web server is the best to choose and how to use the web server with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [article](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/rails-host-comparison-aws-digitalocean-heroku-engineyard)

In early days, or just for testing, you may use Heroku, it has the free instance, and super easy to deploy.

Later on, you may use Digital Ocean, AWS, or Engine Yard. They are cheaper but harder to config

My research, this is the rank for these above hosting providers:

- Easy to deployment: Heroku > Engine Yard > AWS > Digital Ocean
- Cheap price:        Digital Ocean ~> AWS > Engine Yard > Heroku

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I wanna ask about the type of the web server, do i get to choose it (Apache,nginx, etc) or it's up to the hosting provider i use?

Comment: For Heroku & Engine Yard, they are the PAAS (Platform as a service) you can't config server type (I think they are using Nginx), but for AWS or Digital Ocean, they are IAAS(Infrastructure as a service), they just provide you the instance (like machine) you will install library and service to them, so you can freely choose Apache or Nginx

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful